# How to normalize special characters to utf-8 in Python?

Tags: python, decode

I have the following output from a REST request:

```
b'{
    "recipient": {
        "address": "v\xc3\xa4g 4",
    },
}'
```

The `\xc3\xa4` comes from the character `ä`. I'm looking for a simple way to normalize the entire content above so that `\xc3\xa4` is replaced by something meaningful (e.g. `a`).

My script processes addresses in many different languages so I'm looking for something that provides a meaningful replacement across many different special characters.

Comment: The question is not exactly the same as yours, but the answer will probably fit you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633310/791430

Comment: So you want to denormalize `ä` and print only the latin character, right?

Comment: I'm looking to convert `"v\xc3\xa4g 4"` to `"vag 4"`

Comment: Do you know ahead of time which strings you expect to receive? Would a simple string replace work?

Comment: `b'{\n"recipient": {\n"address": "v\xc3\xa4g 4",\n},\n}'.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: I do not know ahead of time what strings I'll receive - essentially this is a script that processes shipping labels for shipments to various countries. The input strings are based on user inputs and may use various country-specific characters. I'm therefore looking for something that takes many such special characters and translates them to the nearest utf-8 equivalent character